# Shared directive scope not binding on initial compile

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm experiencing an issue with sharing scope between two directives. In my use case, I need to isolate the scope of each of the directives and only pass out those items that should be shared.

[***This plunker***](http://plnkr.co/edit/4wYHmR5L2gafBU2b5Str?p=info) illustrates the issue I'm experiencing.

As you'll see, when the application first runs, the scope between the two directives is not being bound, however when one clicks a button after the initial compile, everything works just fine. Why is this occurring? Surely the scope of each directive should immediately be available to the other?

---

UPDATE:

[***Updated Plunker***](http://plnkr.co/edit/4wYHmR5L2gafBU2b5Str)

In reply to one of the answers below. As can be seen, the problem is not that `$scope.item` needs to be defined in the parent controller. It has no problem binding to the parent scope's markup. The issue is that you cannot call on `$scope.item` in your js until the view has compiled. This presents lot of issues if you want to use scope objects passed from one directive to another immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/r4TBQdOTt6WF3wCnUpZt?p=preview) i made for you, it's just the way angularjs bootstrap app, if you don't have defined $scope.item in controller it remains undefined to first use where you assign 'defined' then the item is created on controller scope. Hope that makes sense

Comment: no, this is not a solution. In your example, you're binding to the view, which happens after compile. `$scope.item` does not need to be defined in the parent scope for this. Please see my updated Plunker. The problem is that you cannot use `$scope.item` in your javascript code until the view has compiled, and this presents the issue I need to get around...

Comment: I'd suggest using batarang (AngularJS console for chrome) make few breakpoints and you will see how scope works